# compiling gtk3 app for windows in linux using mingw64

Tags: c, windows, compilation, gtk3, mingw-w64

I need to compile a simple gtk application for windows using Linux. Here is an example from this [link](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html). The compilation via `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) -o example-1 example-1.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)` works as expected. I installed mingw64 packages for Linux in order to compile for windows.
When I run `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) -o example-1.exe example-1.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)` command, I will get this error:

```sh
amb@localhost test]$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) -o example-1.exe example-1.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)
In file included from /usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h:9,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkconfig.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from example-1.c:1:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h: In function '_GLIB_CHECKED_ADD_U64':
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:277:53: error: size of array '_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0' is negative
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:274:47: note: in definition of macro 'G_PASTE_ARGS'
 #define G_PASTE_ARGS(identifier1,identifier2) identifier1 ## identifier2
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:277:44: note: in expansion of macro 'G_PASTE'
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                            ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:423:3: note: in expansion of macro 'G_STATIC_ASSERT'
   G_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof (unsigned long long) == sizeof (guint64));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from example-1.c:1:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h: At top level:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:75:1: error: unknown type name 'uid_t'
 uid_t            g_credentials_get_unix_user      (GCredentials    *credentials,
 ^~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:79:52: error: unknown type name 'uid_t'; did you mean 'pid_t'?
                                                    uid_t           uid,
                                                    ^~~~~
                                                    pid_t
```

I'm new to programming with C and cross compilation. Please explain this problem and provide a solution for me. thx

this is the code (example-1.c):

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
print_hello (GtkWidget *widget,
             gpointer   data)
{
  g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *button_box;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

  button_box = gtk_button_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button_box);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);
  g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button_box), button);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Comment: `$(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)` is using the host's GTK development settings, but you want the target's GTK development settings. Try `$(x86_64-w64-mingw32-pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got another issue on a different scenario. I added some CSS inside the source code, setting a background image for my buttons, It worked as expected using gcc and running it on linux. However, the image was not loaded for the windows executable. I loaded images via url(‘..’) and addressed them relatively. Other CSS stuff worked normally on both machines. What is your idea about this issue?

Comment: @IanAbbott I forgot to notify you!

Comment: Actually, I don't really know much about GTK programming so can't help with your CSS stuff. Besides, it sounds like a separate question!